# grpc library - How to decide at run time for a specific TLS version (1.2 or 1.3) to opt for secure communication by application

Tags: grpc, tls1.3, grpc-c++

[Need Info] Which grpc version having support to configure TLS version at run time?
Such that application can opt TLS version (1.2 or 1.3) at run time.
Is this already supported, if yes then which grpc version need to pick and how to configure the tls version.

grpc v1.30.0 supports only TLSv1.2
grpc v1.32.0 supports TLSv1.3

Didn't found any option to configure TLS version for application at run time.
Please help me out in getting the details like which grpc library supports this option and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to force a specific TLS version from the C++ API. You can follow the progress of https://github.com/grpc/proposal/pull/205, the proposal to add such an API.

Regardless, we recommend using the most recent version of the gRPC library as you can manage, see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases. Any changes to this API will only be available in future versions of the library.